# mutableStateOf updating in view model but no effect in @Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I do have a mutableStateof in my HiltViewModel named loading. I am updating the value of loading from a function in the view model which is being passed to @composable function and being used there.
The case is that the loading value is updating perfectly in the viewModel but not reflecting in the @Composable function.
My viewModel is:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AuthenticationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: AppRepository,
    application: Application
): ViewModel() {
   val loading = mutableStateOf(false)

   fun update() = viewModelScope.launch {
      loading.value = true
   }
}
```

loading value is updated here but not reflecting in the @composable

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    viewModel: AuthenticationViewModel,
    actions: MainActions
) {
    val loading = viewModel.loading.value

    //Loading is another composable function where bool value is passed
    Loading(state = loading)
    CustomNavigationButton(title = "Sign In",enabled = true,onClick = 
    {viewModel.update()})
}
```

Now when I click on the navigation button the view model function is being called and the loading state is also being updated but not reflected back in the @Composable

Loading Composable is:

```
@Composable
fun Loading(state:Boolean) {
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(state) }

    if(showDialog){
        Dialog(onDismissRequest = { showDialog = false }, DialogProperties(
            dismissOnBackPress = false,dismissOnClickOutside = false
        )) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
                contentAlignment= Alignment.Center,
            ){
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `val loading = viewModel.loading.value
` with `val loading = viewModel.loading` and `Loading(state = loading)` with `Loading(state = loading.value)`

Comment: Nope getting the same result

Comment: Add your Loading composable in the question.

Comment: added the loading composable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Issue is in the Loader composable function. if condition was always set to false as the mutable state was never updating in that specific composable function.
Replaced:

```
@Composable
fun Loading(state:Boolean) {
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(state) }

    if(showDialog){
        Dialog(onDismissRequest = { showDialog = false }, DialogProperties(
            dismissOnBackPress = false,dismissOnClickOutside = false
        )) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
                contentAlignment= Alignment.Center,
            ){
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
@Composable
fun Loading(state:Boolean) {
    if(state){
        Dialog(onDismissRequest = {}, DialogProperties(
            dismissOnBackPress = false,dismissOnClickOutside = false
        )) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
                contentAlignment= Alignment.Center,
            ){
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
        }
    }
}
```